# Montar un formulario para impresión

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, macos

Buenas noches estoy tratando de montar un reporte para su impresión pero no me reconoce la ruta.
Me da el siguiente error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \Users\WhiteSnake\NetBeansProjects\MiCrud\src\main\java\reporte\reporteCrud.jasper

Estoy trabajando con Netbeans 11.2, JasperReport sobre Mac os

Este es mi código.

```java
    private void btnReporteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        try {
            MiConexion conectar = new MiConexion();
            Connection cn = conectar.miconexion();
            //creasion de variable tipo jasperreport
            JasperReport reporte = null;
            //crear variable tipo String con el nombre del archivo tipo jasper, se busca la ruta del archivo reporte.jrxml
            String path = "\\Users\\WhiteSnake\\NetBeansProjects\\MiCrud\\src\\main\\java\\reporte\\reporteCrud.jasper";
```

He tratado sólo con

```java
\\src\\main\\java\\reporte\\reporteCrud.jasper";
```

Estoy seguro de la ruta, he probado de varias maneras poner el `path` pero no logro levantar el reporte, me podrían, me pueden ayudar a ver donde esta mi error?

Encontre la soluciona...
En el pom.xml agregar una dependencia...

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no se mucho JasperRepor pero te puedo decir que en el botón no realices operaciones y que las hagas en una clase y luego los llames.

Luego en la ruta:"\Users\WhiteSnake\NetBeansProjects\MiCrud\src\main\java\reporte\reporteCrud.jasper".
creo que le falta el disco y la letra de inicio : **"C:\Users\..."**.
espero haberte ayudado como te digo no se mucho de jasper.